# I need to calculate coefficient t in the student's distribution python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Here is a [Russian site](https://www.kontrolnaya-rabota.ru/s/teoriya-veroyatnosti/tablica-studenta/?n=60&p=0.8) that calculates this value. But I need to count it myself. With df = 60 confidence = 0.8 it should be equal 1.296. I saw [this function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html#scipy.stats.t), but i do not understend how to use this

Comment: so, what have you tried so far and what problem do you face?

Comment: i try to use scipy.stats.t, but i do not understend how to use it for my purposes

Comment: edit your question to include your code

Comment: I poorly understand how to use this library and just tried different things in the hope of getting the desired result. In other words, the problem is not the bugs in the code, the problem is that I'm not sure at all that this is what I need

Comment: Not many people will help you if you just post links. Especially a link that says `Russian site`.  Links can connect to dangerous websites.  For that reason please put relevant information (the minimal needed) right into the question.

Comment: I'll take that into account, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out the answer on another forum, it turns out I needed the distribution quantile for the two-sided t test. And it is calculated as follows:

`scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + 0.80)/2, 60-1)`